# How do i show an image via input while a certain object is selected ( nft card/image previewer )

Tags: javascript, html

How do I use file input to load a picture, store the picture in cookies, or some other to store te picture that doesn't use an alternate language, and only show said picture when a particular object (nft card) is being displayed. The program is basically an image slider that shows information along with a picture pertaining to the current selected nft card.

````
const prevbtn = document.querySelector("#prev-btn");
const nextbtn = document.querySelector("#next-btn");
let cardName = document.querySelector("#name");
let cardDescription = document.querySelector("#description");
let cardPrice = document.querySelector(".eth");
let cardTime = document.querySelector("#time2");
let cardCreator = document.querySelector("span");
let deck = [];
let card;

let formSubmit = document.querySelector(".formsubmit");
let formName = document.querySelector("#form-name");
let formDescription = document.querySelector("#description2");
let formPrice = document.querySelector("#form-price");
let formTime = document.querySelector("#time-left");
let formCreator = document.querySelector("#creator-name");
let formNFTart = document.querySelector("#nft-art")

let selectedFile;

let picShow = document.getElementById("newimagetoggle");
let picChange = document.querySelector(".nft-card-image")
let newElement = document.createElement("input");
newElement.setAttribute("type", "file");
newElement.setAttribute("accept", "image/*");

//NFT Card Class creator
class NFTcard {
    constructor(id, name, description, price, time, creator, image) {
        this.id = id
        this.name = name
        this.description = description
        this.price = price
        this.time = time
        this.creator = creator
        this.imageID = image
    }
};


// set starting card
let currentCard = 0

// create deck to store nft Card creations
deck = [];


// Create new NFT and change NFT Image from user input 
let createNewNFT = function () {

    // new image
    selectedFile = newElement.files[0]
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
        // convert image file to base64 string
        picChange.src = reader.result;
    }, false);

    if (selectedFile) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(selectedFile);
    }

    // retrieve user nft data and place in new nft card object
    let newNftName = formName.value

    newNftName = new NFTcard(`${deck.length}`, `${formName.value}`, `${formDescription.value}`, `${formPrice.value}eth`, `${formTime.value}`, `${formCreator.value}`, `${deck.length}`);

    deck.push(newNftName);

    // clear input fields

    formName.value = ""
    formDescription.value = ""
    formPrice.value = ""
    formTime.value = ""
    formCreator.value = ""
}

picShow.addEventListener('click', function () {
    newElement.click();
});

formSubmit.onclick = function () {
    createNewNFT();
};

// Switch to current card

let switchCard = function () {
    card = deck[currentCard];
    cardName.textContent = card.name;
    cardDescription.textContent = card.description;
    cardPrice.textContent = card.price;
    cardTime.textContent = card.time;
    cardCreator.textContent = card.creator;
    picChange.src = card.imageID
}

// load initial card 
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    switchCard(currentCard);
});

//Next button switch card 
nextbtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    currentCard++;
    if (currentCard > deck.length - 1) {
        currentCard = 0
    };
    switchCard(currentCard);
})

//Prev button switch card 
prevbtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    currentCard--;
    if (currentCard < 0) {
        currentCard = deck.length - 1;
    }
    switchCard(currentCard)
})```
````

Comment: What is this program trying to do? What is the desired output? (it's not creating NFTs, looks more like some UI). Please reduce your question to the actual problem instead of posting all of your source code here. Your question has nothing to do with NFTs, it's a question about JavaScript UI.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion - the question is - how do I use file input to load a picture , and only show that picture when aparticular object (nft card) is being displayed. The program is basically an image slider that shows information along with a picture.

Comment: Ok, then please clean up your question and remove everything that has nothing to do with your problem (Your problem has nothing to do with NFTs, it only concerns displaying images). Then make a minimal reproducable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Then your question will look much friendler and more approachable and you have much better chances to get help.

Comment: Hopefully the updated questions will suffice.

Comment: Please read again: stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
The example, that you present here, needs to be complete. It's missing HTML, so nobody knows, what your query selectors are referring to. Ideally you create an example using jsfiddle or similar, so people can actually play with the code.